# CA1303, DoNotPassLiteralsAsLocalizedParameters, but I'm actually not

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, localization, fxcop

**My code gets the `CA1303` warning** from `Microsoft.Globalization`, "Do not pass literals as localized parameters", **but my code is not actually passing a literal**:

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTitle();
}

private void UpdateTitle()
{
    Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    this.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0} v{1}.{2} Alpha r{3}", this.Text, version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build);
}
```

This code sets the title of the form to something like this, every time it is loaded:

> **MyFormNameAsSetInTheDesigner** v0.1 Alpha r123

(`version.build` actually contains the SVN revision, which is auto-updated at each commit, I do not use `revision` because my versioning scheme uses only 3 numbers, `major.minor.revision`)

*But this triggers the aforementioned warning*, because it thinks I'm setting the titlebar text from a string literal. In fact, I've set `Localizable = True` in the designer, so that the string *is fetched from a resource table*.

I do not want to set the form's title statically because (especially in the alpha and beta stages) I want it to have dynamic version numbers.

#### The question is what do I do so I don't get a warning (for example, which code will do what I'm doing but be considered correct per FxCop, or how can I supress it for that line).

Comment: @Jon The question is what do I do so I don't get a warning (for example, which code will do what I'm doing but be considered correct per FxCop, or how can I supress it for that line).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182187.aspx) for CA1303, the reason for the warning being raised is that you pass a literal string as the second parameter of the `String.Format` method, and in addition the second formal parameter of that particular overload is annotated with `LocalizableAttribute`.

Therefore what the warning wants you to do is to put the string `"{0} v{1}.{2} Alpha r{3}"` as a localized resource in your resource assembly, and refer to it as such. Which is probably a good idea, as technically the structure of the format string and the fixed parts of its contents *are* localizable resources.

If you simply want to make FxCop shut up, you can [annotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute.aspx) `UpdateTitle` accordingly:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization",
                 "CA1303:DoNotPassLiteralsAsLocalizedParameters" )]
private void UpdateTitle() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I see, this makes sense. But how do I do this? (there's a "Resources" tab in the project's properties, but how do I specify the language of the properties I'm setting? For example, I'd like this to be the default, and if other language requires a different format string, to set one just for that language).

Comment: @CamiloMartin: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I just wanted to note that the instructions Microsoft gives are terribly awkward and overcomplicated. You just need to: 1) edit resources in the project properties' "resources" tab, 2) fetch the resource from `Properties.Resources.YourResourceName` in the code, and 3) to localize you just create (from the resource file template) a `Resources.en-US.resx` (example language code) sitting alongside `Resources.resx`, then edit a property with the same `YourResourceName` used before. Done. Microsoft actually tells you to create satellite assemblies and use a resource manager - you don't need to!

Comment: @CamiloMartin: Could you help? 1) leads to the ressource dialogue with 3 columns (Name, Value, Comment) It is unclear to me what i should edit there. 2) should be clear: every field inside MyResourceFile can be accessed from code by `Properties.Resources.MyResourceFileName.MyAttribute`. 3) i believe is partly clear: i add an additional file for example `Properties.Resources.MyResourceFileName.en-US.resx` and inside this xml file i have to add the same fields / attributes: `<data name="MyAttribute" ...><value>myTranslation</value></data>` Can you confirm 1-3 and clarify step 1?  Thanks

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree 1) You put the desired variable name (variable name rules apply), the contents of the variable (a string), and optionally a comment. For example: name: "ApplicationName", value: "Fartilizer Pro 2014 360 One", comment: "Until I settle on a name". 2) Didn't remember having to do that, maybe for the "default" resources you don't have to? It's been a while. 3) You don't need to edit the resx files textually, the editor on step one does that for you.

Comment: this may sound silly, but it is not better to define a string variable prior to that line, and the assign it?

Answer (score 0):

A general way to ignore this warning is to add the following to your to your `.csproj` file(s):

```
<NoWarn>CA1303</NoWarn>
```